# symfony Form with multiple steps

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to create a form with multiple steps in that:
First field displayed should be a phone number type.
Once that is submitted I want to perform a lookup to see if there is a user with that phone number.

If a user is found then I need a second field for verification, so I create a zip code field.

I am currently doing this with one controller and one form type:

**SearchType:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('phoneNumber', PhoneNumberType::class, array(
            'default_region' => 'US',
            'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL))
        ->add("finished", HiddenType::class, array(
            "data" => "no"))
        ->add("submit", SubmitType::class);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form) {
            $phoneNumber = $form->get('phoneNumber')->getData();
            $one = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Phone')->findOneByPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);
            if($one){
                $form->remove("submit"); 
                $form->remove("finished");                
                $form->add("zipCode", TextType::class);
                $form->add("finished", HiddenType::class, array(
                    "data" => "yes"));               
                $form->add("submit", SubmitType::class);
            }
        };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $formModifier($event->getForm());
        }
    );
    $builder->get('phoneNumber')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent());
        }
    );
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);        
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $form->get("finished")->getData() == "Yes") {
    //...
}
```

So, I'm not even sure if I am on the right track. I am currently trying to use the Hidden field "finished" to let me controller know when to actually do the work with the submitted data, however "finished" never gets set to "yes" and I am not sure why.

Aside from that, is there a better way for me to be doing this?

I looked into [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) but that required the underlying data to be an object (wouldn't work with Array) and I didn't think I wanted it to be in this case since I am just using the data entered to perform a query.

Comment: you might try https://github.com/zikula/Wizard although I am not sure it will do what you need either, but worth a look

Comment: I'll check that out. Can anyone comment on why `finished` never gets set to yes? Does it have to do with the handleRequest in my controller? Is that reverting it back to no because that's what was in the request? Any other better ways of doing this?

Comment: One option would be to build a complete form with all fields in Symfony, and create a jQuery plugin to show / hide parts of that form depending on user input. The shown form parts can  look like separate forms, but once submitted (in the final step), you get all data nicely in Symfony controller. Just an idea